# Create/Initialize a bean before some other bean in SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have my Application.java like this:

```
package server;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;    

@SpringBootApplication(exclude=HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean fact = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
        fact.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return fact;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My problem it's that I want to create the bean for the sessionFactory before starts to work the @ComponentScan of the @SpringBootApplication but I don't know how can I do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understood is you want to first initialize the `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean` before any bean gets initialize which actually uses the `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.`

Try using the [@DependsOn](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html)

 You can move the HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean to a different config class for eg. go through this [example](https://www.boraji.com/spring-dependson-annotation-example)